# how to access item data bound field in nested repeater and sum different data bound element

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I want to make class sheet where I displayed courses and multiple marks of multiple student in repeater control.
Now I want to access different courses marks and sum in total marks column from that field are bound with inner repeater result

```
protected void OuterRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Repeater rptInner = ((Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("InnerRepeaterTitle"));
        Repeater InnerRepeaterCourseResults = ((Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("InnerRepeaterCourseResults"));
        HiddenField hfStudentID = ((HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("hfStudentID"));
        //SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from View_CourseTitle where ProgramName='" + DropProgram.SelectedItem.Text + "' and SemesterNo='" + DropSemester.SelectedItem.Text + "' order by CourseID", con);
        //DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        //ad.Fill(ds);
        //rptInner.DataSource = ds;
        //rptInner.DataBind();

        SqlDataAdapter ad1 = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from view_Result where StudentID='" + hfStudentID.Value + "' and SemesterNo='" + DropSemester.SelectedItem.Text + "' order by CourseID", con);
        DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
        ad1.Fill(ds1);
        InnerRepeaterCourseResults.DataSource = ds1;
        InnerRepeaterCourseResults.DataBind();
    }
```